# How to `cmd /V:ON` in line with another command to run sequentially

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

What I'm trying to accomplish through the command line is loop files in a directory and just renamed them to one up sequential number. I can accomplish that with the following

```
set/a fileNum = 1 & for %f in (*.txt)  do ( rename %~nf%~xf !fileNum!%~xf & set/a fileNum += 1 )
```

The issue however, is that I cant do variable expansion without doing `cmd /V:ON` on the command line first.
I've try to do it this way

```
 cmd /V:ON & set/a fileNum = 1 & for %f in (*.txt)  do ( rename %~nf%~xf !fileNum!%~xf & set/a fileNum += 1 )
```

but that also did not work. So my question is, is there a way around this. According to this to this thread [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493132/setting-cmd-exe-von-flag-without-starting-new-instance) thread I should be able to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` on the cmd line, but that does not work. Is there a away around this.

Comment: `cmd /v:on` opens a new instance of `cmd`. You want to execute the part after *within* the new instance. If you do  `&` the part after it is executed in the original instance *after `cmd /c` ends*. (you don't want `cmd & set & for` but `cmd /v:on "set & for"` (read the output of `cmd /?` very carefully, maybe a second or even third time if needed - it's not very intuitive)

Comment: Why not create a batch file and put new commands on a new line rather than creating a one liner?

Comment: @LPChip for reasons I rather not get into, I don't have that option. If I did I wouldn't ask this question. (rediculous work constraints)

Comment: @Stephan I'm open to other suggestions on how to accomplish the main goal. This is simply the solution that I've been able to cook up.  If you have another way to rename files with cmd that wont require inline expansion I'm all ears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want / have to do it as a one-liner directly on the command prompt:

```
@>nul set filenum=1&@for %f in (*.txt) do @(cmd /v:on /c ECHO ren "%~nxf" "!fileNum!%~xf"&>nul set/a fileNum+=1)
```

Remove the save-guard `ECHO` after verifying it does what you want

Answer (score 3):

#### I cant do variable expansion without doing `cmd /V:ON on` the command line first.

Correct. However the following should work:

```
cmd /V:ON /c "set/a fileNum = 1 & for %f in (*.txt)  do ( rename %~nf%~xf !fileNum!%~xf & set/a fileNum += 1)
```

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [CMD.exe (Command Shell) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.

Comment: Thanks David. Must appreciative. I will read up , I have a lot to learn.